# Can't read a text file

Tags: c++, linux

I've been coding for a basic Snake Game in C++. I wanted to store the  top 5 high-scores in a text file so I could display them in the end.

I'm only showing the relevant code here.

Code:-

```
#include<fstream>
ofstream outfile("HighScore.txt");
ifstream infile("HighScore.txt");

int main()
{
    int a[5]={0},temp;
    infile.clear();
    infile.seekg(0,infile.beg);
    if(infile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++) infile>>a[i];
        infile.close();
    }
    else cout<<"Unable to open";
    char temp1;
    Setup();
    do
    {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
        if(gameOver==0)
        {
            cout<<"\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1H"<<flush;
            cout<<"\t\t\t\tSNAKE GAME"<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\n\n\t\tYour score is:"<<score;
            cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\tDo you want to restart the game?\n\t\t Press y to continue\n\t\t";
            temp1=(char)getch();
            for(int i=4;i>=0;i--)//Used to make sure that the scores remain in a descending order
            {
                if(score>a[i])
                {
                    if(i==4) a[i]=score;
                    else
                    {
                        temp=a[i];
                        a[i]=score;
                        a[i+1]=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(outfile.is_open())//Used to write the high-scores in "HighScore.txt"
            {
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++) outfile<<a[i]<<endl;
            }
            else cout<<"Unable to open";
            outfile.close();
        }
    }
```

It seems that the code for writing the file is working and the output is always the current score at the top along with 4 0's.
For example:- If I scored 5 this time then the output will be
5
0
0
0
0

So according to me I'm not able to read the current values of the file because of which the values in the array a is always 0.

[I'm new here so I'm sorry if my formatting or description here is not up to the mark]

Comment: You will likely not be able to open the same file twice. And anyway, creating an `ofstream` will replace any existing file with the same name. You might be able to use a single `fstream` for both reading and writing.

Comment: @BoPersson I used fstream instead of ifstream and ofstream and it worked. Thank you!!